# How to resolve multiple onclicklistner that are using together

Tags: android

This is my code and I can't solve this. I've been very confused from couple of days but the error does not disappear. I see an error in onClickListner and some other places. Please help me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Color;
  import android.graphics.Typeface;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     this.   OptionB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setEnabled(false);
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setEnabled(false);
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setEnabled(false);
          ArabicQuiz.this.temps.cancel();
          String str = ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.getText().toString();
          if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(str))
          {
              ArabicQuiz localArabicQuiz = ArabicQuiz.this;
            localArabicQuiz.lavel = Integer.valueOf(1 + localArabicQuiz.lavel.intValue());
            ArabicQuiz.this.dynamiclevel = localArabicQuiz.lavel.intValue();
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setTextColor(-16777216);
            if (ArabicQuiz.mpright != null) {
                ArabicQuiz.mpright.start();
            }
            ArabicQuiz.this.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                  ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setEnabled(true);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setEnabled(true);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setEnabled(true);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setBackgroundResource(2130837507);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setTextColor(-1);
                ArabicQuiz.this.kbc(ArabicQuiz.this.var4, ArabicQuiz.this.lavel.intValue());
                ArabicQuiz.this.initCount();
                ArabicQuiz.this.temps.start();
              }
            }, 5000L);
            return;
          }
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setBackgroundResource(2130837505);
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setTextColor(-16777216);
          ArabicQuiz.this.temps.cancel();
          if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.getText().toString()))
          {
              ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setTextColor(-16777216);
          }
          for (;;)
          {
            if (ArabicQuiz.mpwrong != null) {
                ArabicQuiz.mpwrong.start();
            }
            ArabicQuiz.this.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                Intent localIntent = new Intent();
                localIntent.putExtra("total", ArabicQuiz.this.min);
                localIntent.putExtra("status", "Ø¢Ø³ÙØŒ Ø­Ø§ÙˆÙ„ Ù…Ø±Ø© Ø£Ø®Ø±Ù‰");
                ArabicQuiz.this.finish();
                ArabicQuiz.this.startActivity(localIntent.setClass(ArabicQuiz.this, End.class));
              }
            }, 5000L);
            return;

            if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.getText().toString()))
            {
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
              ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setTextColor(-16777216);
            }
            else if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.getText().toString()))
            {
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
              ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setTextColor(-16777216);
            }
          }
        }
      });

      this.OptionC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
          @Override 
         public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setEnabled(false);
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setEnabled(false);
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setEnabled(false);
          ArabicQuiz.this.temps.cancel();
          String str = ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.getText().toString();
          if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(str))
          {
              ArabicQuiz localArabicQuiz = ArabicQuiz.this;
            localArabicQuiz.lavel = Integer.valueOf(1 + localArabicQuiz.lavel.intValue());
            ArabicQuiz.this.dynamiclevel = localArabicQuiz.lavel.intValue();
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setTextColor(-16777216);
            if (ArabicQuiz.mpright != null) {
                ArabicQuiz.mpright.start();
            }
            ArabicQuiz.this.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                  ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setEnabled(true);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setEnabled(true);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setEnabled(true);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setBackgroundResource(2130837508);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setTextColor(-1);
                ArabicQuiz.this.kbc(ArabicQuiz.this.var4, ArabicQuiz.this.lavel.intValue());
                ArabicQuiz.this.initCount();
                ArabicQuiz.this.temps.start();
              }
            }, 5000L);
            return;
          }
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setBackgroundResource(2130837505);
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setTextColor(-16777216);
          ArabicQuiz.this.temps.cancel();
          if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.getText().toString()))
          {
              ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setTextColor(-16777216);
          }
          for (;;)
          {
            if (ArabicQuiz.mpwrong != null) {
                ArabicQuiz.mpwrong.start();
            }
            ArabicQuiz.this.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                Intent localIntent = new Intent();
                localIntent.putExtra("total", ArabicQuiz.this.min);
                localIntent.putExtra("status");
                ArabicQuiz.this.finish();
                ArabicQuiz.this.startActivity(localIntent.setClass(ArabicQuiz.this, End.class));
              }
            }, 5000L);
            return;
            if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.getText().toString()))
            {
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
              ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setTextColor(-16777216);
            }
            else if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.getText().toString()))
            {
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setTextColor(-16777216);
            }
          }
        }
      });
      this.OptionD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
          @Override

        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setEnabled(false);
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setEnabled(false);
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setEnabled(false);
          ArabicQuiz.this.temps.cancel();
          String str = ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.getText().toString();
          if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(str))
          {
              ArabicQuiz localArabicQuiz = ArabicQuiz.this;
            localArabicQuiz.lavel = Integer.valueOf(1 + localArabicQuiz.lavel.intValue());
            ArabicQuiz.this.dynamiclevel = localArabicQuiz.lavel.intValue();
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
            ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setTextColor(-16777216);
            if (ArabicQuiz.mpright != null) {
                ArabicQuiz.mpright.start();
            }
            ArabicQuiz.this.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                  ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setEnabled(true);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setEnabled(true);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setEnabled(true);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setBackgroundResource(2130837509);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setTextColor(-1);
                ArabicQuiz.this.kbc(ArabicQuiz.this.var4, ArabicQuiz.this.lavel.intValue());
                ArabicQuiz.this.initCount();
                ArabicQuiz.this.temps.start();
              }
            }, 5000L);
            return;
          }
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setBackgroundResource(2130837505);
          ArabicQuiz.this.OptionD.setTextColor(-16777216);
          ArabicQuiz.this.temps.cancel();
          if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.getText().toString()))
          {
              ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
              ArabicQuiz.this.OptionB.setTextColor(-16777216);
          }
          for (;;)
          {
            if (ArabicQuiz.mpwrong != null) {
                ArabicQuiz.mpwrong.start();
            }
            ArabicQuiz.this.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                Intent localIntent = new Intent();
                localIntent.putExtra("total", ArabicQuiz.this.min);
                localIntent.putExtra("status", ");
                ArabicQuiz.this.finish();
                ArabicQuiz.this.startActivity(localIntent.setClass(ArabicQuiz.this, End.class));
              }
            }, 5000L);
            return;
            if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.getText().toString()))
            {
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionC.setTextColor(-16777216);
            }
            else if (((Question)ArabicQuiz.this.var4.get(ArabicQuiz.this.index.intValue())).getAns().equalsIgnoreCase(ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.getText().toString()))
            {
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setBackgroundResource(2130837504);
                ArabicQuiz.this.OptionA.setTextColor(-16777216);
            }
          }
        }
      });
      this.imgFivtyFivty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
            ArabicQuiz.this.lifeLineFivtyFivty();
        }
      });
      this.imgPhoneAFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
            ArabicQuiz.this.loadPhoneAFriend();
        }
      });
      this.imgAudiancePoll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
         ArabicQuiz.this.lifeLineAudiancePoll();
        }
      });
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception localException) {}


  protected void onPause()
  {
    super.onPause();
    this.temps.pause();
  }

  protected void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();
    this.temps.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Maybe you missed the second `"`?

Comment: As @ByteHamster suggested `localIntent.putExtra("status", ");` is missing double quotes. Please post the error that you get.

Answer (score 1):

I did notice that this line

```
localIntent.putExtra("status", ");
```

Should be...

```
localIntent.putExtra("status"," ");
```

Comment: i  get error that ,,The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, long)